# RecyclerView Adapter Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

There is something I'm missing when I'm setting `RecyclerView` to my adapter. The App crashes when running it. Can anyone please help me with identifying the issue?

```
// My adapter
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.myViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<item> mData;

    public Adapter(Context mContext, List<item> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.background_img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getBackground());
        holder.profilePhoto.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getProfilePhoto());
        holder.tv_title.setText(mData.get(position).getProfileName());
        holder.tv_nbFollowers.setText(mData.get(position).getNbFollower() + " Followers");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView profilePhoto, background_img;
        TextView tv_title, tv_nbFollowers;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            profilePhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
            background_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_background);
            tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            tv_nbFollowers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_nb_follower);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I set the `RecyclerView` with the adapter

```
RecyclerView recList = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
List<item> mlist = new ArrayList<>();
mlist.add(new item(R.drawable.fish0, "Bass", R.drawable.profile0, 2500));
mlist.add(new item(R.drawable.fish1, "Mondo Bass", R.drawable.profile1, 3500));
mlist.add(new item(R.drawable.fish2, "Large Mouth Bass", R.drawable.profile2, 5500));
mlist.add(new item(R.drawable.fish3, "Bass", R.drawable.profile3, 10500));
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, mlist);
recList.setAdapter(adapter);
recList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Here is the Logcat error

```
2018-10-19 19:17:20.479 10635-10635/fishingfreaks.ffapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fishingfreaks.ffapp, PID: 10635
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fishingfreaks.ffapp/fishingfreaks.ffapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at fishingfreaks.ffapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: The app crashes when running it.

Comment: Crashes?  Do you have a debugger that shows you the error and where it happens?  Does it just exit silently?  Stack Overflow isn't just a debugging service - you'll need a more specific question to get a good answer.

Comment: I updated the question with more details from the Logcat. The app exits silently.

Comment: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference**     your logcat already specified the problem. Your recyclerview is null. And you're trying to setHasFixedSize(true) on that recyclerview. Check your activity xml that id of recyclerview is specifically there.

Comment: Downvoting as logs clearly shows where and what the problem is. Learn to debug and understand logs. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you please share the whole code from the `onCreate` function?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. The issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException`. So the layout item that you are referring to, is not found while you are trying to call the `setHasFixedSize` function on it.

This might happen for two reasons.

- You might have referred to the wrong layout item id. Double check the id `rv_list`. Does it has the same spelling in your layout as well?
- If the above condition is okay (i.e. your layout does have the `rv_list` as the id of your `RecyclerView`, then you might need to check if you have set the content view in your activity's `onCreate` function. Do you have the `setContentView` function call in your `onCreate` function? If not, then add the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_with_recyclerview)` as the first statement after the `super` call of your `onCreate` function.

Comment: This explanation helped me solve the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference at fishingfreaks.ffapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) at

From the logs it is clear that you are setting `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize()` at a point where instance of your **recylerview is null**. See line 31 of your MainActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!